# How to setup one common CMS and two CD server in different region in Azure Pass Architecture?

Tags: azure, paas, azure-resource-manager

Currently, we have scaled environment setup on Azure Pass i.e one CM and one CD server in a common region. Now we have created one more site but its for another region and due to compliance policy we can't set it up into our existing CD server. So we need to create separate CD server for that particular country region in Azure. Can anyone please suggest us the approach for this type of architecture i.e having common CMS for two CD server which are hosted on different region? Is that possible to first setup the CD server on azure and then change the core and Xconnect connection string? What are the basic step which we need to follow for this setup?

Comment: If I'm understanding you correctly, you might be able to simply spin up another App Service in your desired region and then configure your solution to have multiple "publishing targets" so as to be able to publish certain items to another Web Database hosted elsewhere?

Comment: @DaveGoosem thanks, i got the approach but for spinning up app service into another region can we create single web app with CD server role using Sitecore azure ARM templates? Also what about the CMS and another region CD connectivity for core, xconnect, xdb, exm ? so for different region CD server do need to change all these connection string to my CMS server expect web db?